# Having problems with GPG Key

Tags: apt, updates

I asked a question about this and still no response. I am having a big problem with AnyDesk. I have removed it from my Ubuntu 22.04 but every time I run an update, this is what I get

```
An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key   
  is not available: NO_PUBKEY xxxxx
```

Comment: I removed anydesk but I am still getting this error when I update.

Comment: You mention removing `anydesk` but what did you remove?  Did you remove the source? or only the package (*deb*, *snap* etc), as the message implies you didn't remove everything (*forgetting the source I bet*).  If you see that message on `sudo apt update` then you've left the source on your system.

Comment: You are correct. It's ok now. Thanks.

Comment: @guiverc what you suggested is actually the solution! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You mention removing `anydesk`, but what did you remove?

Did you remove the source? or only the package (*deb*, *snap* etc), as the message implies you didn't remove everything (*forgetting the source I bet, as that is what the error message relates to*).

If you see that message on `sudo apt update` then you've left the source on your system.

Comment: answered as requested...  *I voted to close question as 'problem went away' seeing little value in the comment (now answer)*